# TextMate map key for next complete to command + spacebar

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I found a lot of tutorials and forum questions around remapping key bindings in Textmate and for the most part I know what needs to be done as far as copy the KeyBindings file and then make the changes needed. More on what I am talking about here http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/

I am interested in re-mapping the esc key for nextComplete to control + spacebar. The problem is I am having a hard time finding what the code is for the spacebar or if this is even supported.

I mainly do actionscript development in eclipes and code hinting dialogue is triggered by this key combo and I would like to have the same in Textmate. Hitting the esc key kind of sux. I thought I would get used to it but the fact is that it just kills the flow of typing the rest of your code.

I could use some help figuring out what he code is for the space bar. I know control key is the ^ symbol. I tested this by changing the keybinding to ^s and it remapped just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one can be done with the OS X gui:

System Preferences, Keyboard, Click Keyboard Shortcuts Tab
Click the little Plus, and choose Application: Textmate.app, Menu Title: Next Completion, Type Command Space (or Control Space) and click Add and that should work. You might want to remove conflicting shortcuts - possibly spotlight?

[image]

For future reference, I used [Key Codes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) to find the key for space is: \UF20